# Grouping objects of array for knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an objects array that has 27 length:

```
[object(array)]
....
....
```

Each item in this array is empty or consists of an objects of array which has properties as shown below. This could have several loops so it will have many objects.

```
function MainTests(testName, section, totalExpected, totalPasssed, totalDuration, loopExpected, loopPassed, loopDuration) {
    var self = this;           
    self.sectionName = section;
    self.testName = testName;
    self.totalPassExpect = totalExpected;
    self.totalPassRate = totalPasssed;
    self.totalDuration = totalDuration;
    self.loopPassExpected = loopExpected;
    self.loopPassRate = loopPassed;
    self.loopDuration = loopDuration;                                                  
}
```

I want to group by `sectionName` and `testName` like this:

```
{
    section: sectionName,
    tests: [testName:testName, totalPassExpect: totalExpected........loopDuration:loopDuration..]
}
```

I tried this but it only groups it by `sectionName`:

```
self.GroupMainTest = ko.computed(function () {
    var mainTestArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allMainTests.length ; i++) {
        var group = {};
        var result = allMainTests[i];
        if (result.length != 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                if (group[result[j].sectionName] == undefined) {
                    group[result[j].sectionName] = [group[result[j].sectionName]];
                }
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].sectionName)
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].totalPassExpect)
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].totalPassRate)
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].totalDuration)
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].loopPassExpected)
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].loopPassRate)
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].loopDuration)
                group[result[j].sectionName].push(result[j].testName)
            }
            mainTestArray.push(group);
        }
        else {
            mainTestArray.push(result);
        }
    }
    return mainTestArray;
});
```

My goal is to achieve similar to [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5jHhQhyZsZFT0UiRGhw?p=preview).

Can you help?

Comment: you might want to proof read your question.. It was hard to read... But if I understood you correctly, I would suggest not only checking sectionname before pushing but also testName....

sorry your code is just a bit confusing and your question is harder to understand :(

Comment: Can you please just produce a simple image showing what output you are expecting

Comment: Please, instead of showing this code, add a sample of the entry array, and the expected result. All the information in your question is irrelevant.